# Execute script from share directory

Tags: python, debian, samba

I want to execute python script from network share (samba).
Local and distant OS are on the same Debian.
At the moment i have Permission denied message...
And of course sudo & chmod doesn't works.

If possible I don't want to do a local copy of this file. The goal is execute script directly from the share directory on the local computer.

Thx to all !

Comment: just mount the remote directory using cifs.

Comment: The [`mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) man page covers mount options you can use to control permissions exposed on the client side of a CIFS mount, but if your problem is about those (as opposed to about writing code), it's off-topic on StackOverflow and is a better fit for [unix.se] or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). Search for `mode` in that man page to skip straight to documentation relevant to UNIX permissions.

Comment: (of course, you can always `python foo` even without the execute bit; it's only `./foo` that requires +x and the absence of a `noexec` mount flag).

Comment: @nosklo cifs is working like a charm ! Thx also Charles Duffy for the tip ;)